# Excel crashing when pulling up userform (with initialize) if VBA window hasn't been viewed during session

Tags: excel, userform, vba

**Background:**

I am developing a builder in Excel using a userform.  The userform is loaded by selecting a specific cell, then the userform_initialize starts.

---

**Issue:**

If I have not loaded VBA during the session I am looking to load the userform, Excel crashes.  I get an error message (bottom of post) that says I am accessing  memory that has been deallocated.

---

**Question:**

In review of my Option Explicit code, I am unsure of the issue, as it runs once VBA has been opened during the session.  Does anyone know if there is some type of loop error in a userform_initialize subroutine?

Any help/advice would be appreciated.  The code is in the next subsection of this post.

---

**Code in Question:**

```
Dim r As Long, c As Long, v As Long
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    c = ActiveCell.Column
    With Sheets("Bldr")
         For v = 0 To 28
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "a", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 1 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "b", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 31 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "c", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 61 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "d", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 91 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "e", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 121 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "f", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 151 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "g", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 181 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "h", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 211 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "i", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 241 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "j", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 271 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "k", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 301 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "l", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 331 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "m", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 361 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "n", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 391 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "o", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 421 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "p", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 451 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "q", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 481 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "r", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 511 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "s", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 541 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "t", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 571 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "u", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 601 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "v", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 631 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "w", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 661 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "x", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 691 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "y", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 721 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "z", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 751 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "1", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 781 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "2", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 811 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "3", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 841 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "4", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 871 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "5", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 901 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "6", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 931 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "7", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 961 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "8", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 991 + v).Value = True
             If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "9", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 1021 + v).Value = True
         Next v
    End With
```

---

**Error Code:**

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:                     APPCRASH
  Application Name:                       EXCEL.EXE
  Application Version:                    16.0.8431.2236
  Application Timestamp:                  5a9aa882
  Fault Module Name:                      unknown
  Fault Module Version:                   0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:                 00000000
  Exception Code:                         c0000005
  Exception Offset:                       00000000
  OS Version:                             6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:                              1033

Additional information about the problem:
  LCID:                                   1033
  skulcid:                                1033
```

Comment: ...I just took a guess thinking I might be having too much happening in the loop... broke the 35 lines into 10-10-10-5 and it works.  Apparently I was using too much memory.

Answer (score 0):

You're using:

```
.Cells
```

.. but there's no parent object designation.

You need to wrap a worksheet object around all the lines which use .Cells, like this:

```
With Worksheets("NameOfYourSheet")
    If Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v), "a", "")) < Len(.Cells(r, c + 3 + v)) Then Controls("CheckBox" & 1 + v).Value = True
    ' etc...
End With
```

Comment: Sorry about that; in stripping out the other non-issue code, I forgot to carry my with statement.  Will update the post to show that, too.